# how to login in to psql with your admin details

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, terminal, postgresapp

hi am following the following tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qw--VYLpxG4&t=2224s

and when i add psql into my path and then type it into the terminal it asks for my administrator datails of which i give then it shows this

```
psql: error: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "aarushsharma"
```

how do i find out the password for aarushsharma?

Comment: You specified the password when you created the user `aarushsharma` so you are the only one who knows that password

Comment: i never created an account in postgresql with the name ```aaarushsharma``` but i do have it on my desktop thats why i assumed it had my desktop credentials and thats when it said the error

Comment: then why do you try to connect with that user? To specify a different user use `psql -U ....`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name because that username has postgis installed i managed to install it through postgres app but i can't install postgis on the default postgres user so i want to try and login to the other user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change METHOD in pg_hba.conf file from md5 to trust, restart postgresql server and change your user password

> ALTER USER aarushsharma WITH PASSWORD 'your_password';

and set METHOD to md5 again

Comment: how do i access the pg_hba.conf file?

Comment: i have now managed to access the pg_hba.conf file but everything was already set to trust

Comment: what OS do you have?

Comment: if everything is already set to trust, try connecting the database using postgres user, probably user aarushsharma doesn't exist.

Comment: I can connect with Postgres but I just did this command when I got into the account ```\du``` and it showed aarushsharma there as a superuser

Comment: when I got into the Postgres account

Comment: hi my OS is MacOS

Comment: this is strange because trust parametr in pg_hba.cong allows anyone that can connect to the PostgreSQL database server to login as any PostgreSQL user they wish, without the need for a password 

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/auth-pg-hba-conf.html